# ContentProviderを使用する時に、Failed to find provider info for...　というエラーが返ってくる

Tags: android

現在ContentProviderを使ったアプリを作成しているのですが「Failed to find provider info for taro.thanks.mycontentprovider」と、「java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{taro.thanks/taro.thanks.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException」というエラーが返ってきます。色々と調べてみたところ、Manifestファイルに追記しなければいけないことが分かり、以下のように追記したのですが、それでも同じエラーが返ってきます。

```
<provider
        android:authorities="taro.thanks"
        android:name=".MyContentProvider"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

そもそもContentProviderの使い方が間違っているのでしょうか？
エラーが出る場所は下記のコードの`while(cursor.moveToNext())`の行です。

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MyContentProvider.URI_MAN, new String[]{MyContentProvider.COLUMN_VOICE}, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

ContentProviderを継承したMyContentProviderクラスのqueryメソッドは以下のようになっています。

```
@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Cursor c = db.query(uri.getPathSegments().get(0), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }
```

また、UriはMyContentProviderクラスのフィールドで

```
public static final Uri URI_MAN = Uri.parse("content://taro.thanks.mycontentprovider/" + TB_MAN);
```

と定義しています。
間違っているところがあれば、指摘していただきたいです。
すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Manifestファイル

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="taro.thanks" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="taro.thanks.MyContentProvider"
            android:name=".MyContentProvider"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: 記憶だけで書きますが、
どの ContentProvider が使われるかは URI により決定します。
なので URI をどのように生成しているかと、
ある ContentProvider がどのような URI に反応するか、
この2点が重要になるはずです。
特に、質問には前者が欠けているようですので、
補ってはいかがでしょう。
あとエラーメッセージはできれば省略しないほうが良いです。
恐らくこのケースでは、
省略された場所にもっとも重要な情報が書かれていると考えられます。

Comment: `name` 属性等クラスの場所指定関係がおかしいと、件のエラーになるような気がします。`"MyContentProvider"` の部分を `".MyContentProvider"` かパッケージ名含めたフルパス指定にする、 `authorities` 属性の指定を見直す、`provider` タグの位置も確かめる、等が試してみることにあるかな。

Comment: KoRoNさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。KoRoNさんのおっしゃる箇所を追記いたしました。宜しくお願いします。

Hiroshi Yamamotoさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。providerタグの中をご指摘の通り何通りか変更してみたのですが、それでも同じエラーのままでした。。。

Comment: 暇人の戯言です。
AndroidManifest.xml内では大文字、小文字が別物として認識されますが、authorityの文字列が不一致な気がします。`android:authorities="taro.thanks.MyContentProvider"`とPG上の`URI_MAN = Uri.parse("content://taro.thanks.mycontentprovider/" + TB_MAN)`の中に書いてある`taro.thanks.mycontentprovider`が別物として認識されてませんか。(両方小文字にしてみればいけるんじゃない、みたいな。)
とりあえず、PG上で[***調べてみる***](http://qiita.com/ginsyama/items/574b13b755554252c9b5)のはどうでしょう。

Comment: user3009331さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示いただいたリンク先でauthorityを取得したところ、taro.thanks.MyContentProviderとなっており、フォールドで定義したUriの小文字を大文字に変えて実行したところ動かすことができました！本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://qiita.com/ginsyama/items/574b13b755554252c9b5
上記のサイトのやり方でautoritiesを取得してログで確認し、自分のフィールド上のUriの文字列を取得したautoritiesの文字列に合わせたら動かすことができました。（`content://taro.thanks.mycontentprovider`を`taro.thanks.MyContentProvider`に修正しました）